# How to select current page or by page id using jqmData

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a multi-page document and I'm binding to the pageshow event of page "myId":

```
$('#myId').live('pageshow', renderMyIdTempalates);
```

I'm applying my JSON templates with PURE like this

```
function renderMyIdTempalates(event) {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    var $page = $("#myId");
    // do ajax call
       $page.children( ":jqmData(role=header)" ).directives(...).render(data); 
       $page.children( ":jqmData(role=content)" ).directives(...).render(data);
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
 }
```

Initially I was using

```
$('#myId').directives(...).render(data);
```

to apply my templates. This caused problems since the selector didn't include the jqm attributes. So I used the jqmData method to grab the header and content to apply my templates. This works fine, but how do I select the entire document that I'm working with? I would prefer to apply my templates to the entire document once.
I tried:

```
$(":jqmData(role=page)") // selects all pages
$(":jqmData(id=myId)") // no luck
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the selector

```
div:jqmData(id="myID")
```

should work. just remember that myID should not be the id of that div.
That page div should have a parameter data-id="myID"

Comment: Thanks, that allows me to select the page with all the jqm attributes. Seems like PURE isn't working right with some of the page attributes... but this is a separate issue.